# Sorting output against lists to return non-matching objects in powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have two variables holding lists

```
  $ab = 'apple','pear','orange','tangerine'

  $cd = 'banana','mango','pear','orange'
```

When I try to sort them using the following

```
   $ya = $ab| Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $cd}
```

I am not getting left with

```
    $ya = 'apple','tangerine'
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if an element is contained or not contained in an array you can
use `-in` or `-notin` .... like this:

```
$ab = 'apple','pear','orange','tangerine'
$cd = 'banana','mango','pear','orange'
$ya = $ab | Where-Object { $_ -notin $cd }
$ya
```

Comment: I actually used notcontains so it was PV2 compliant but same principal. I marked it as correct, thanks

Comment: @Hulahup I don't have to worry about PV2 compatibility anymore. But I'm glad it was helpful. ;-)